# brew: Not linking to the latest python (symlinks in /usr/local/opt)

Tags: homebrew

Even after running `brew link --overwrite python@3.10`, the symlink `/usr/local/opt/python@3` does not point to version 3.10. Worse, it removed the `/usr/local/opt/python` symlink (that was also pointed to 3.9)

```bash
l /usr/local/opt/ | grep python
lrwxr-xr-x    29 vivekragunathan admin  2 Jun 12:07   python@3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/
lrwxr-xr-x    29 vivekragunathan admin 18 May 14:39   python@3.8 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.13_1/
lrwxr-xr-x    29 vivekragunathan admin  2 Jun 12:07   python@3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/
lrwxr-xr-x    28 vivekragunathan admin  8 Jul 12:17   python@3.10 -> ../Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.5/
```

What do I have to do so that I have symlinks `python` and `python@3` under `/usr/local/opt` point to the latest version (`3.10` now)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you saw `python@3` was pointing to `python@3.9` is because `python@3` is [an alias](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/1e114215ba77c81c82304e544ff2e495bf46eb9f/Aliases/python%403) to `python@3.9`. There is [a WIP PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/87075) for migrating the   alias to point to python@3.10`.

Comment: So along the same lines, am I correct in assuming that python alias was from 2.x? 

Comment: which line do you refer to wrt python@2? I think we did remove python@2 stuff and associated formulae as it is no long supported in the newer macOS versions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I had python 2 originally on the machine and there was a symlink in the above list that was pointing to python2. I removed it to make sure I don't use python2 by any chance.

Comment: Cool, yeah, you should be always able to use `which python` to tell which python version is being used.